# python split the list into sublist at certain strings

Tags: python

I have a list of lists:

```
[['H', '0'], ['S', '3', '1.00'],
 ['33.8650000', '0.0254938'],
 ['5.0947900', '0.1903730'],
 ['1.1587900', '0.8521610'],
 ['S', '1', '1.00'],
 ['0.3258400', '1.0000000'],
 ['S', '1', '1.00'],
 ['0.1027410', '1.0000000'],
 ['****'],
 ['He', '0'], ['S', '3', '1.00'],
 ['98.1243000', '0.0287452'],
 ['14.7689000', '0.2080610'],
 ['3.3188300', '0.8376350'],
 ['S', '1', '1.00'],
 ['0.8740470', '1.0000000'],
 ['S', '1', '1.00'],
 ['0.2445640', '1.0000000'],
 ['****']]
```

I want to split the whole list into sublists at points where the list element is `****`.

So the output should look like:

```
[['H', '0'], ['S', '3', '1.00'],
 ['33.8650000', '0.0254938'],
 ['5.0947900', '0.1903730'],
 ['1.1587900', '0.8521610'],
 ['S', '1', '1.00'],
 ['0.3258400', '1.0000000'],
 ['S', '1', '1.00'],
 ['0.1027410', '1.0000000'],
 # the ['****'] was here!
 ]

[['He', '0'], ['S', '3', '1.00'],
 ['98.1243000', '0.0287452'],
 ['14.7689000', '0.2080610'],
 ['3.3188300', '0.8376350'],
 ['S', '1', '1.00'],
 ['0.8740470', '1.0000000'],
 ['S', '1', '1.00'],
 ['0.2445640', '1.0000000']]
```

Thanks,

Comment: Is the pattern ['****'] is constant or variable ??

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.index()` method to find `['****']` in the list. Beware though, that it throws a `ValueException` if the element is not found, so you have to use `try` and `except` blocks to catch it.

```
lsts = [['H', '0'], ['S', '3', '1.00'], ['33.8650000', '0.0254938'], ['5.0947900', '0.1903730'], ['1.1587900', '0.8521610'], ['S', '1', '1.00'], ['0.3258400', '1.0000000'], ['S', '1', '1.00'], ['0.1027410', '1.0000000'], ['****'], ['He', '0'], ['S', '3', '1.00'], ['98.1243000', '0.0287452'], ['14.7689000', '0.2080610'], ['3.3188300', '0.8376350'], ['S', '1', '1.00'], ['0.8740470', '1.0000000'], ['S', '1', '1.00'], ['0.2445640', '1.0000000'], ['****']]
split_lsts = []
while True:
    try:
        index = lsts.index(['****'])
        split_lsts.append(lsts[:index])
        lsts = lsts[index+1:]
    except ValueError:
        break
```

Comment: what if there are more than one '****' ?

Comment: What do you mean? Provide an example.

Comment: he is saying if pattern is ['**'] or ['********']  instead of ['****']

Comment: Or is he saying that there is `[['****'], ['****']]'`? He said **more than one**, not **more than four**.

Answer (score 0):

To split when element is ['****']:

```
a = [['H', '0'], ['S', '3', '1.00'], ['33.8650000', '0.0254938'], ['5.0947900', '0.1903730'], ['1.1587900', '0.8521610'], ['S', '1', '1.00'], ['0.3258400', '1.0000000'], ['S', '1', '1.00'], ['0.1027410', '1.0000000'], ['****'], ['He', '0'], ['S', '3', '1.00'], ['98.1243000', '0.0287452'], ['14.7689000', '0.2080610'], ['3.3188300', '0.8376350'], ['S', '1', '1.00'], ['0.8740470', '1.0000000'], ['S', '1', '1.00'], ['0.2445640', '1.0000000'], ['****']]
new_list=[]
for el in a:
    if el == ['****']:
        print new_list
        new_list = []
        continue
    else:
        new_list.append(el)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as reference Given ['****'] is only pattern

```
a = [['H', '0'], ['S', '3', '1.00'],
 ['33.8650000', '0.0254938'],
 ['5.0947900', '0.1903730'],
 ['1.1587900', '0.8521610'],
 ['S', '1', '1.00'],
 ['0.3258400', '1.0000000'],
 ['S', '1', '1.00'],
 ['0.1027410', '1.0000000'],
 ['****'],
 ['He', '0'], ['S', '3', '1.00'],
 ['98.1243000', '0.0287452'],
 ['14.7689000', '0.2080610'],
 ['3.3188300', '0.8376350'],
 ['S', '1', '1.00'],
 ['0.8740470', '1.0000000'],
 ['S', '1', '1.00'],
 ['0.2445640', '1.0000000'],
 ['****']]

  mid = a.index(['****'])
  print(a[:mid])
  print(a[mid+1:])
```

Comment: This works when splitting the list in half, but if there was more than one `['****']` then it wouldn't.

Comment: i was about to write that

Answer (score 0):

With `itertools.takewhile` function:

```
import itertools

result = []
idx = 0
while idx < len(lst):   # lst is your initial list of sublists
    result.append(list(itertools.takewhile(lambda l: l[0] != '****', lst if not result else lst[idx:])))
    idx += len(lst) if not result[0] else len(result[-1]) + 1
```

Outputting resulting sublists:

```
for sub_l in result:
    print(sub_l)
```

The output:

```
[['H', '0'], ['S', '3', '1.00'], ['33.8650000', '0.0254938'], ['5.0947900', '0.1903730'], ['1.1587900', '0.8521610'], ['S', '1', '1.00'], ['0.3258400', '1.0000000'], ['S', '1', '1.00'], ['0.1027410', '1.0000000']]
[['He', '0'], ['S', '3', '1.00'], ['98.1243000', '0.0287452'], ['14.7689000', '0.2080610'], ['3.3188300', '0.8376350'], ['S', '1', '1.00'], ['0.8740470', '1.0000000'], ['S', '1', '1.00'], ['0.2445640', '1.0000000']]
```